# all integer ordered pair $(a,b)$ in $a^3+a^2+4a+4=b^2$

Tags: number-theory

> Find all integer ordered pair $(a,b)$ in $a^3+a^2+4a+4=b^2$

$\bf{My\; Try::}$ Let $f(a) = a^3+a^2+4a+4,$ Then Using Derivative test

$$f'(a)=3a^2+2a+4=3\left[a^2+\frac{2}{3}a+\frac{4}{3}\right] = 3\left[(a+\frac{1}{3})^2+\frac{11}{9}\right]>0$$

Now i did not understand how can i solve it, Help required, Thanks

Comment: $$a^3+a^2+4a+4=a^2(a+1)+4(a+1)=(a+1)(a^2+4)$$

Now $(a^2+4,a-1)$ must divide $(a^2+4,a^2-1)$ which must divide $a^2+4-(a^2-1)=5$

**Case** $\#1:$ If $a+1=5b\iff a=5b-1, a^2+4=(5b-1)^2+4=5(5b^2-2b+1)$

$$(a+1)(a^2+4)=5^2 b(5b^2-2b+1)$$

Now $(b,5b^2-2b+1)=1\implies$ both have to be perfect square.

If $b=c^2,5c^4-2c^2+1=d^2\iff(5c^2-1)^2+4=5d^2$

**Case** $\#2:$ Else $(a^2+4,a-1)=1$

We need both to be  perfect square.

Comment: Thanks  lab bhattacharjee ,plz explain me one more time i did not understand from second line.

Comment: @jantheron, As $a^2-1=(a-1)(a+1)$  and as $$a^2+4-(a^2-1)=5$$